# Why are my co-ordinates slightly off in my map in R (SF package)?

Tags: r, mapping

This is my first time trying to map northing and easting co-ordinates in R using the SF package. The co-ordinates appear to be laid out in the expected shape but they are not sitting on top of the correct place on the map. They should be sitting over Northern Ireland but instead appear north of Northern Ireland over the ocean.

```
sf_points_ptr = st_as_sf(fig2_map_df, coords = c(x = "Easting", y = "Northing"), crs = 29902)

tmap_mode('view')

qtm(sf_points_ptr, dots.col = "blue")
```

Here is an image of the output.[image: Northern Ireland mapping]

I have tried changing the CRS value but can't seem to find one that works for me. I don't understand about projections in R so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: only solution is to find the correct crs. you can try 2157, 2158, 29903 or 29901 and see if that works. Else: try some more or go to the owner of the coordinates/data and ask.

Comment: I tried all of those you suggested and they didn't work, thanks. Where would I find a list of all the CRS options?

Comment: you can try https://epsg.io/ but if you really do not know where the data is coming from, and have no idea to narrow the options down, you might be in for a LOT of trying..

Comment: Thanks Wimpel. I actually randomly came across 7405 and it worked - it's the British National Grip + ODN Heigh.

Answer (score 1):

CRS = 7405 (British National Grid + ODN Height)